# Problems with scale of simulator XCode

Tags: ios

OS X Mavericks, XCode 6.2.

I've got some problems with scale of simulator: I'm seeing only a half of screen.

How can I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You're not seeing half screen, you have to apply constraints to your label so it looks like in the storyboard.. (look that the status bar of the emulator is looking good)

Comment: How can I apply constraints to label?

Comment: This is a complete different question, I suggest you to take a look to AutoLayout..

Answer (score 0):

Technically you cant do it through xcode, but you can do it by going to /Library/Preferences and edit com.apple.iphonesimulator.plist file. Change the value for SimulatorWindowLastScale.

Comment: There is no file in this folder